# Store all most used directories and query for most used directories containing a string

Tags: c

This is an implementation of [zoxide](https://github.com/ajeetdsouza/zoxide) in C, it uses a shell alias to `cd` between directories it stores(as csv in form of <count,path>) or when the directory is invalid it searches for closest matching directories

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#if defined(__linux__)
#include <linux/limits.h>
#else
#include <sys/syslimits.h>
#endif
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

#define PATH_ALLOC_SIZE PATH_MAX


typedef struct {
  char *path;
  size_t freq;
} path_rate_t;

const char *easycat(const char *l, const char *r);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
  if(argc>1){
    char *data_home = getenv("XDG_DATA_HOME");

    const char *homedir;
    if ((homedir = getenv("HOME")) == NULL) {
      homedir = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
    }
    if(data_home==NULL){
      data_home=malloc(strlen(homedir)+23); // /.local/share/coxide/\0 = 23
      if(data_home==NULL){perror("malloc() returned NULL");}
      strcpy(data_home, homedir);
      strcat(data_home, "/.local/share/coxide/");
    } else{
      if(realloc(data_home, strlen(data_home)+9)==NULL) {perror("realloc returned NULL");} // /coxide/\0 = 9
      strcat(data_home, "/coxide/");
    }
    const char* DBFILE = easycat(data_home, "main.csv");
    const char* TMPDBFILE = easycat(data_home, "tmp.csv");


    mkdir(data_home, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
    FILE *dbfp = fopen(DBFILE, "r");
    bool new_db=false;
    FILE *tmpdbfp = fopen(TMPDBFILE, "w");

    if(dbfp==NULL){
      new_db=true;
      dbfp=fopen(DBFILE, "w+");
    }
    if(tmpdbfp==NULL){
      tmpdbfp=fopen(TMPDBFILE, "w");
    }
    if(dbfp==NULL||tmpdbfp==NULL){
      fputs("Unable to open file", stderr);
      exit(2);
    }

    if(argv[1][0]=='-'){

      char *resolved_path = malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_ALLOC_SIZE);
      if(resolved_path==NULL){perror("malloc()");}
      
      realpath(argv[2], resolved_path);
      if(new_db){
        fprintf(dbfp, "1,%s\n", resolved_path);
        return 0;
      }
      path_rate_t buf = {malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_ALLOC_SIZE), 1};
      bool prev_exist=false;
      while(fscanf(dbfp, "%zu,%s", &buf.freq, buf.path)==2){
        if(strcmp(buf.path, resolved_path)==0 || buf.path[0]=='\0'){
          fprintf(tmpdbfp, "%zu,%s\n", buf.freq+1, buf.path);
          prev_exist=true;
        }else{
          fprintf(tmpdbfp, "%zu,%s\n", buf.freq, buf.path);
        }
      }
      if(!prev_exist){
        fprintf(tmpdbfp, "1,%s\n", resolved_path);
      }
      rename(TMPDBFILE, DBFILE);
    } 
    else{
      if(new_db){
        fputs("DBFILE was empty, use valid paths to cache directories", stderr);
        return 0;
      }
      size_t i=0, li=0;
      path_rate_t most = {malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_ALLOC_SIZE), 0};
      path_rate_t buf = {malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_ALLOC_SIZE), 1};

      while(fscanf(dbfp, "%zu,%s", &buf.freq, buf.path)==2){
        i++;
        if(buf.freq>most.freq){
          if(strstr(buf.path, argv[1])){
            //NOTE: dest is as large as source, do I need to use stpncpy
            stpcpy(most.path, buf.path);
            most.freq=buf.freq;
            li=i;
          }
        }
      }
      if(li!=0){
        i=0;
        fseek(dbfp, i, SEEK_SET);
        while(fscanf(dbfp, "%zu,%s", &buf.freq, buf.path)==2){
          i++;
          if(li==i){
            fprintf(tmpdbfp, "%zu,%s\n", most.freq+1, most.path);
          } else {
            fprintf(tmpdbfp, "%zu,%s\n", buf.freq, buf.path);
          }
        }
        rename(TMPDBFILE, DBFILE);
        puts(most.path);
      } else{
        puts(homedir);
      }
    }
    free((void *)DBFILE);
    free((void *)TMPDBFILE);
    fclose(dbfp);
  }
  return 0;
}

const char* easycat(const char *l, const char *h)
{
    char *comb = malloc(strlen(l) + strlen(h) + 1);
    if(comb==NULL){perror("malloc()");}
    strcpy(comb, l);
    strcat(comb, h);
    return comb;
}
```

Since it needs to be almost as fast as regular cd, I would appreciate if there were comments on performance or whether there is any unsafe behaviour

The shell wrapper function

```sh
o(){
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        \builtin cd ~
elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = '-' ]; then
        \builtin popd
elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -d "$1" ]; then
        \coxide - "$1" # compile the c named coxide
        \builtin cd "$1"
else
        \builtin cd $(coxide $1)
fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Minor: avoid the [Schlemiel_the_Painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm) algorithm**

Remember the length of the string `l` points to.

**Do not attempt copy if allocation failed.**

```
const char* easycat(const char *l, const char *h) {
  size_t l_length = strlen(l);
  char *comb = malloc(l_length + strlen(h) + 1);
  if(comb==NULL){ 
    perror("malloc()");
  } else {
    strcpy(comb, l);
    // strcat(comb, h);  // Do not use strcat
    strcpy(comb + l_length, h);
  }
  return comb;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   if(data_home==NULL){perror("malloc() returned NULL");}
>   strcpy(data_home, homedir);
> ```

So when `data_home` is null, we print an error message and then go on to use the null pointer anyway?  That's UB.

We do the same with `resolved_path` and `comb`, and worse with `buf.path` and `most.path`.

> ```
>   if(realloc(data_home, strlen(data_home)+9)==NULL) {perror("realloc returned NULL");} // /coxide/\0 = 9
>   strcat(data_home, "/coxide/");
> ```

When `realloc()` succeeds, and returns a non-null pointer, we go ahead and continue using the *old* pointer?  That's also UB.

> ```
>   fputs("Unable to open file", stderr);
> ```

Message should be a whole line (ending in `\n`).  We should be more helpful, and say *which* file couldn't be opened, and why.

> ```
> const char* DBFILE = easycat(data_home, "main.csv");
> const char* TMPDBFILE = easycat(data_home, "tmp.csv");
> ```

Don't use all-caps for things that are not macros - that unnecessarily panics readers.

> ```
>   path_rate_t most = {malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_ALLOC_SIZE), 0};
>   path_rate_t buf = {malloc(sizeof(char)*PATH_ALLOC_SIZE), 1};
> ```

`sizeof (char)` can only be 1, so the multiplication is pointless.

> ```
> free((void *)DBFILE);
> free((void *)TMPDBFILE);
> ```

Don't cast object pointers to `void*` - that's a valid implicit conversion.

`easycat()` measures `l` too much.  Since we use `strlen()` already, we should reuse the result rather than have `strcat()` measure it again.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything I could do to increase the performance? because it takes too long when the csv file is too long. Also what error code do I send on exit() when malloc returns NULL?

Comment: Any non-zero exit status should be fine.  The main performance problem you have is that you read the whole file every invocation - that's pretty much unavoidable when we have a separate process involved.  To fix that, we'd need to convert to a daemon service or implement as a shell function (caching the data until the file is modified).

Comment: [`EXIT_FAILURE`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/EXIT_status) would be a good choice. Also, instead of `perror()`, consider using [`err()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/err), which should be available on Linux and BSDs, and for which you can write a drop-in replacement function to support platforms which don't have this function.